# Entity Framework classgeneration is not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am very new to Web API and Entity Framework. I am creating a small application after going through Microsoft tutorial. Here is what I did. I created a new ASP.NET web application and then chose Web API from the ASP.NET 4.5.2 templates. I added  a model class by clicking on `Model -> Add New Item` and chose data from the left panel and chose ADO.Net Entity Data Model from the right side. Please see this screenshot:

[image]

I chose EFDesigner from database in "Choose Model Controls" window and established the connection. I tested the connection successfully. I chose my table from the database. I chose Entity Framework 6.x in the "Which version of Entity Framework do you want to use?" window and then I selected my table. That created a bunch of classes in the `Model` folder shown on this screenshot:

[image]

I was expecting to see the properties for all the columns of my table, but the .cs class is totally empty. All I see there  is the below message

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I generate the properties of all the database table columns in my Model class through entity framework. I am using Visual Studio 2017 version 4.7.03062

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using `code first` or `db first` ?

Comment: follow this link and try:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-web-api-crud-logics-using-entity-framework-without-writing-single-code/

Comment: I am using db first

Comment: then try the link above i shared, it should be able to help you to find your issue